# Apache Felix and Spring boot application : Class not found issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, osgi, apache-felix

I wrote a spring boot application which was working fine without any issues. Then I changed pom and added activator class and make it a Felix OSGI bundle. Then I was able to install it with Felix console as well.

But when I start it with Felix controller, I was getting following error,

```
g! start 21
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle company.iot.devops [21].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2276)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:739)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at company.iot.devops.IOTMain.main(IOTMain.java:10)
        at company.iot.devops.osgi.Activator.start(Activator.java:35)
```

Then I tried with

```
<Embed-Dependency>!company*;*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```

In the POM and resolved that issue. But now I am getting different issue,

```
16:51:03.914 [Gogo shell] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [company.iot.devops.IOTMain]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataRea
....
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle company.iot.devops [42].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2276)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)
....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
```

I can see jar file spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar in the bundle and it reffered from "Embedded-Artifacts" in the MANIFEST.MF as well. 
Not sure why Spring boot can't find this class.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should decide. Either Spring or OSGi. You should not mix the two; otherwise, you will generate a huge amount of researching work that will have no benefit for you ever.

Comment: hmm but why is that? why spring is so much special? Why can't we run Spring on OSGI as a normal Java App?

Comment: Anyway as I explained on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620492/felix-osgi-embedded-application-issue/37624045#37624045  now I am running OSGI on Spring boot application (not Spring boot on OSGI). I hope this will eliminate those issues I am facing.